# Did the Beach intend to raise Arisu's rank for his valuable cards?

Tags: alice-in-borderland

In the first series of Alice in Borderland, Arisu eventually tracks down the rumoured Beach and is told that he will be
remunerated for the valuable playing cards that he has brought to them.

He subsequently receives an executive role for his performance in a deductive game.

However, from his armband during the Witch game he only has a rank of 315 at the end of his time on the Beach. By comparison and from the tags I can see from a brief scan of the relevant episodes:

1. Hatter
2. Keiichi Kuzuryū

3-6. Aguni/Ann/Mira/Niragi?

7. Chishiya

Blonde nervous militant - 13

Admittedly Arisu is not exactly getting in on the ground floor but it doesn't seem like he got any bump at all for bringing in valuable cards (or for making executive). I remember a line of dialogue saying his promotion was under discussion but did this ever happen or was it overtaken by the dramatic events that quickly followed?

Comment: I BELIEVE you mean remunerated, not renumerated.  Remuneration is compensation, like money.  Renumerated would be, well, changing his number :)  I've edited the question with that assumption, but please roll it back if I misunderstood.  (Renumerated COULD make sense... giving him a higher number.. but still think you meant Remunerated :) )

Comment: Absolutely correct - thank you for the edit.